# Jquery Keypres function not working FireFox

Tags: jquery, firefox, onkeypress

I have the following JQuery function which validates a text field for numbers and one decimal only. It works fine in Crome but its not working in Firefox.  Anyone know how i achieve the same in Firefox?

```
$('#amount').keypress(function(event) {                     
         checkAmount(event, $(this));
});

function checkAmount(event, inputBox){
    if((event.which != 46 || $(inputBox).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
       event.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) says:

> Note: as the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.

You may want to use [`$.keydown`](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/).